# Vetur error 2300 Duplicate identifier '(Missing)'

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vetur

I'm having this weird error with Vetur in a typescript nuxt.js application. It shows this error message on the first line of all the components whether it's an empty line or has the  tag.

I'm not sure when this error started to appear or what does it even mean?

[image: Duplicate identifier '(Missing)']

Any help will be appreciated, thanks a lot!

Comment: Some actual code or a [repro] could be helpful here.

Comment: I don't know how it started to happen or how does the error originate so I don't have a reproducible example. also, the error exists on the first line of any given vue component so the code of any given component won't be relevant. I'd be happy to help in any other way.

Comment: Here https://prnt.sc/24oq1jg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turned out that this was because of Vetur experimental `templateInterpolationService` property. By turning it to `false` in the `vetur.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  settings: {
    /* .. */
    'vetur.experimental.templateInterpolationService': false
    /* .. */
  }
};
```

Vetur stopped the unexpected interference with my components.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is like chopping your arm off when your finger hurts!  If you disable `templateInterpolationService` you lose a big part of the value of Vetur.

For me Vetur v0.35.0 broke when I upgraded `typescript > 4.4`

You can check which version(s) of typescript you're using by typing `npm ls typescript` in your project root.

If you're running `typescript` `4.4.4` (or lower), try this:

Restart Vue Lanaguage Server (in VSCode): 
View -> 
   Command Palette.. -> 
      Vetur:Restart VLS (Vue Language Server)

If you're running `typescript` `4.5` or higher, you will probably run into this error.  Still working to find a fix in this case.

Alternatively, to force your environment to use an older version of typescript across the board, you can ensure your version of npm is 8.3+ and use the new "overrides" section of package.json:

```
...
  "overrides": {
    "typescript": "4.4.4"
  },
...
```

Comment: Getting this error all of a sudden today. This doesn't fix the problem for me unfortunately.

Comment: Here is the [github issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/3323). It's said to have been fixed 15 days ago in [0.36.0](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/releases/tag/v0.36.0)

Comment: I've since disabled Vetur and transitioned to Volar.  It was a pretty smooth transition so far.

Answer (score 1):

Making sure the gloabal ts version of vscode `<=4.4.4`. It may be some dependences(like `@microsoft/api-extractor`) using a newer `typescript` .

Creating `vetur.config.js`. Setting `"vetur.useWorkspaceDependencies": "false"` in `settings`. example:

```js
module.exports = {
    settings: {
        "vetur.useWorkspaceDependencies": false,
        "vetur.experimental.templateInterpolationService": true
    }
}
```

Checking vscode OUTPUT panel in `Vue Language Server`, may:

```
[INFO ] Find node_modules paths in xxxxxxx - 247ms
[INFO ] Loaded bundled typescript@4.4.4.
[INFO ] Loaded bundled prettier.
[INFO ] Loaded bundled @starptech/prettyhtml.
[INFO ] Loaded bundled prettier-eslint.
[INFO ] Loaded bundled prettier-tslint.
[INFO ] Loaded bundled stylus-supremacy.
[INFO ] Loaded bundled @prettier/plugin-pug.
```

Success!

Answer (score 0):

It was fixed in vetur [v0.36.0](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/releases/tag/v0.36.0)

> Fix template type-checking when typescript >= 4.5. [#3323](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/3323),[#3424](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/3424).

It's not on vscode store yet, but you can download the [`vetur-0.36.0.vsix`](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/releases/download/v0.36.0/vetur-0.36.0.vsix) directly from github release and install manually:

[image]